# How relative are "Software recommendation" and "Opinion based", and why is all OK in this case?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, opinion-based

I got this test on "Reopen review".

Note: there is a question with similar answer. But only mine question has a "picture" that helps to identify the problem on the fly and without doubts. This is important - since this is the story that not everyone can trust.

[image]

IMHO this is both a software recommendation and opinion based question, however, according to Stack Overflow, should be reopened.

I can only welcome this fact - reopen is my favorite review type. But I saw so many closed questions where topic was "recommend me a lib" so have no energy to argue with the opinion that they should be closed.

If there are some "yes they are, but..." could you explain it?

And if SO changes its politic on opinion based and software recommendations - could you advertise it loudly?

Comment: It's a bad audit. The system thinks it's a good question because it got a lot of upvotes.

Comment: This is cool! Community votes to make those topics more liberal. And SO provide this possibility for the community. I'm impressed.

Comment: [Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297405/how-can-i-convert-data-structure-to-json-in-perl6)

Comment: @Roman You misunderstand. Audits are chosen automatically. Since this one didn't have any down-votes or close votes and had a lot of up-votes, it was chosen as a "known good" question, whereas it is obviously not. But now the meta-effect will kick in, and as soon as the question receive a single down-vote it will be removed from the audit pool.

Comment: There you could misunderstand what is "obviously not (good question)". What I understand - community can protect some questions from the "reviewers"  - and this is cool. Even if this is "unstable protection" and 10 time more "reviewers" can still close the question.

Comment: No, this question is not "protected". A bad question with many upvotes and no down-votes is liable to be sent to review as a "fake review", and it will usually be reported or downvoted because of it, since it will confuse users, as it happened to you. But upvotes do not protect a question from closure at all.

Comment: To be even more clear: rules have not changed. That is still an off-topic question.

Comment: I understand that they do not give 100% protect from closing. But it is still a form of protection - since my review was .. how would you say it ... "get off" ?

Comment: No, if this question has actually been closed and you had actually clicked “leave closed”, the system wouldn’t had complained. It only did because it was a fake review.

Comment: Hmya, what is unreasonable here?  A [perl] programmer shouldn't use json?  Or shouldn't be allowed to use the word "best"?  Do avoid reviewing by trigger words.  Look at what the tag community is thinking about it, that does require looking at the Q+A.  At which point you can never fail such an audit.  Do consider an edit to remove the phrase you find objectionable, probably helps users in future audits as well.

Comment: @HansPassant , there is a sense to "move" such questions and answers to the specific league since they generate a lot of "votes" just for blablabla , but definitely this status should be not named "closed". SO is about gamerfication and every game should have rules.

Comment: You hate questions that help a lot of people and want them destroyed?  That only makes sense if you hate failing an audit more.  Pretty common btw.

Comment: " want them destroyed" - as I understand closed are not deleted. they are still indexed, nobody destroys them. just those votes are not count in the Game :) But "closed" should be renamed to "offside".

Comment: I asked about best module, because nobody writes his own code to handle JSON. In Perl 5, there is a module JSON which works perfectly. Perl6 is very young, so question cannot be how to parse JSON, but is there some efficent module to parse JSON or stringify it. I can remove best or module, but it doesn't change the problem, how can one efficiently parse JSON in PERL6 and this can be only done with a generic module. So looking  for the best module seems consistent for me. Efficient would be more specific.

Comment: Plaute, don't worry everything is OK with you and your question. It just get specific status "votes not count". You even can continue asking such questions. I will plus it to maintain positive status -  I do not understand people who minus it. Minus and close (at least for "recommend me lib") should not be related.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij To keep someone from having negative votes is **not** a reason to vote, you should be voting on the merits of the question alone

Comment: Nick A : my vote, my rules

Comment: All this mess is interesting :) To a some extent, I agree with you about usage of the word best (I guess best is the problem), even though I thought arguing on words was only a french passion. I can edit it and replace best by efficient which would be more acceptable. Be useful is the most important thing. Say me if you agree.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij Doesn't mean we can't call you on your misuse of them.  Sure, you *can* vote to mitigate a negative value; nothing will happen if you do so, but it's not what the voting system was meant for.  Vote on the content *alone*.  Not on what you believe the score should be.

Comment: Ok, it seems that deleting question is the best solution :)

Comment: @Plaute :) best solution is just ignore those "reviewers" with theirs bureaucratic totalitarism, earn some reputation, and support your values effectively, I vote to reopen it :)

Comment: @Roman, but the question is off-topic. Voting to re-open questions you **know** are off-topic for the site seems like a wilful misuse of the open/close vote privilege to me.

Comment: So....first you complain that you failed a review audit, which is understandable, because it is actually off-topic, and it was a bad audit.  You then totally reverse that choice and vote to reopen it after the community rectifies the problem?  That makes no sense at all.

Comment: @yivi, this is how vote system works.

Comment: You have already **tried** to vote to close that question. You are making no sense.

Comment: @fbueckert  - i do not complain about failed audit. I was glad that this my audit was failed. I like such surpises when community can protect theirs values against something very "doubtfull" (even if is very clear for you).

Comment: *"IMHO this is both software recommendation and opinion based"* - *Votes to reopen question after it was closed* - ... ... wat?

Comment: @yivi - I tried to follow game rules, to reopen more questions that it is possible to reopen. my own opinion - it is not a big problem to keep it open.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij You disagreeing with the community is only going to lead to frustration and anger in this case; recommendations are totally off-topic, and will stay that way.  All you did by bringing it to Meta's attention is ensuring that it didn't slip through the crack it was in prior to this question.

Comment: "disagreeing with the community"  - that is not a big problem in democratic systems. I just want to know real community opinion. and that is why voting exist.

Comment: Disagreement isn't a problem, no.  Referring to those you disagree with as, ["bureaucratic totalitarism"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375119/how-relative-is-software-recommendation-and-opinion-based-and-why-all-is-ok#comment636791_375119), and implying they are wrong and should just ignore them, however, shows a bit more than just a passing investment in the decision.  Democracies need people who disagree.  But they need disagreement in a more open state of mind.  Otherwise, all it does is cause a rift.

Comment: If you want not to be on the side of "bureaucratic totalitarism" - just learn that in civilian relationships since Romans Law apart the "Rule"  also Fairness and Reasonableness are the same important. "Why we delete it? Because of rules" - this is not enough, and this is not whole story.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij The rules _were_ created by the community. Originally, recommendation questions were allowed. But we learnt the hard way that they attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: That is true. But I do not discuss reasonableness and fairness of the rule by itself and do not discuss the source of the rule. I discuss understanding of the status, I state: "this is not bad question, this is question that is not count".  And I discuss why my opponents not only delete the q but also minus it? I do not see there any reason. They afraid of spam - nonsence. They are adepts of bureaucracy totalirism - close.

Comment: *"this is not bad question"*, then why did you fail the audit? Failing means you opted to "Leave Closed" (because the audit was automatically chosen from "good" questions), which you wouldn't do if it wasn't a bad question. *"this is question that is not count"* What? Sorry I don't understand what you're trying to say here.

Comment: @Nick I know not only current rules but also how to do review to get a badge :)  That not means I think that current situation with "recommend me a lib" questions is good. And moreover do not consider those minuses on this concreate question as something good -  opposite I consider them as a trap - people loose right objectives.

Comment: "IMHO this is both a software recommendation and opinion based. And this question, according to Stack Overflow, should be reopened." - did you miss a "not" there? If not, then your question makes little sense to me.

Comment: @Cristik I think they missed a "however": *"IMHO this is both a software recommendation and opinion based, **however**, this question, according to Stack Overflow, should be reopened."*